# Ошибка window.Market.Liner is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть проблемка, при вызове выдает ошибку

```
window.Market = {}
new window.Market.Liner($('body .content .products .liner')).activate()
window.Market.Liner = function(place, options=null) {
........
........
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменяйте местами определение функции и ее вызов

```
window.Market = {}
window.Market.Liner = function(place, options=null) {
  ........
}
new window.Market.Liner($('body .content .products .liner')).activate()
```

Или определите метод `Liner` при объявлении самого объекта

```
window.Market = {
  Liner: function(place, options=null) {
    ........
  }
}
new window.Market.Liner($('body .content .products .liner')).activate()
```